# html: how to use attribute:value in checkbox

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Question:

How does this attribute `value` work? I googled on line, but did not find examples on how to use `value` with check box.If u can demonstrate with an example, really appreciate.

Comment: Really, you didnt find anything on basic html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the attribute value to a string. Then, if the form control is successful (i.e. has a name, is checked and isn't disabled), that value will appear in the form data (associated with the name of the control).

Note that since you are using PHP, you need to change the name to `vehicle[]` so that PHP's form processing library will present the submitted values as an array (`$_POST['vehicle']`) instead of discarding all but the last one.

Answer (score 0):

when you try to use

```
$_POST['chkname']
```

then it will return the value of that particular 'chkname'(checkbox).
Here you have to use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>

if (isset($_POST['vehicle'])) {
   $vehicles = $_POST['vehicle'];
   // $vehicles is an array of selected values
}
```